# Trying to reverse a bin file

Tags: binary-analysis, ghidra, arm, binwalk

I'm trying to reverser a bin file with Ghidra, without success for the moment, I can't find any functions in the decompiled file.
he bin file is for an ARM 32bits, I'm pretty sure this is an stm32, so I've followed some tutorial for use Ghidra with stm32, [this one for example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U70unElrYbs&t=1059s)

1. select cortex little and set flash address
2. set flash_mirror address
3. set RAM address
4. Analyse the bin file

but I have no functions when I analysed the file. Any idea ? Encrypted firmware may be ? Here is the [BIN file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1agrlZX29LU0TV7H9ZcsPQshiZ3ztbfSM/view?usp=sharing), I've also try ti work with binwalk, without success

Comment: I have just started working on firmware. Can I get the code for entropy analysis and by any chance tell me how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is encrypted. Entropy is to high.

[image]

Comment: Yep it was also my guess after using binwalk. It will be hard to decrypted without boot loader

Comment: How do you distinguish encryption from compression based alone on entropy? Couldn't it equally be compressed instead of encrypted?